# replace this text comparison in swift

Tags: ios, swift

This works but I am trying to figure out a better way to write it. I want to replace this if condition. I have multiple cases like this

```
if text == "a" || text == "ac" || text == "acc" || text == "acco" || text == "accou"
            || text == "accoun" || text == "account"
        {
            flagAccount = false
        } else {
            flagAccount = true
        }
```

I thought of using CharacterSet but cant seem to figure it out

Comment: You could use `["a", "ac", ...].contains(text)`. But if we thing about it, reversing the "logic", it's a prefix... Is `text` a prefix of "account"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The condition is equivalent to

```
"account".hasPrefix(text) && text != ""
```

Note hat `text != ""` is needed because `"account".hasPrefix("")` is true.

As Rob suggested, you might write this in an if statement like so, using `!text.isEmpty` might be nit more readable:

```
if !text.isEmpty, "account".hasPrefix(text) {

}
```

Comment: @Rob Ah! I didn't know you could use `,` in regular old if statements.